# Lisp: Benefits of lists as code over arrays as code?

Tags: lisp, list, array

Question for lisp programmers:

Lisp code is lisp data, usually lists.  Is there an advantage to code being lists over code being arrays?

Would macros be easier to write/faster to run?

You can assume that, in such a language (you could call it "arrap"), elements can be deleted from or inserted into arrays and that the arrays would grow and shrink as needed.

Comment: By that definition, an array is merely a list, and the difference is semantics of storage.

Comment: voting to send to SO, since this is pretty technical

Comment: Please explain how an array would be different from a list?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Lists are much more versatile than arrays. With lists, you can recurse (e.g., for mapping or folding) by cdring down a list. This doesn't work for arrays; you'd have to pass in the array index too.

For example, this is a simple implementation of `map` and `fold` that take one list only:

```
(define (map1 f l)
  (if (null? l) l
      (cons (f (car l)) (map1 f (cdr l)))))

(define (left-fold1 f init l)
  (if (null? l) init
      (left-fold1 f (f (car l) init) (cdr l))))
```

How would you do that for arrays, without having to pass in another argument (for the index)? (Remember, Lisp and Scheme have no pointers, at least none that user code can touch.)

---

Also, lists can share storage, but arrays cannot. Take this Scheme code for example:

```
(define (x-world x)
  (cons x '(world)))

(define hello-world (x-world 'hello))
(define goodbye-world (x-world 'goodbye))
```

Here, `hello-world` has the value `(hello world)` and `goodbye-world` has the value `(goodbye world)`.

There is one important fact, though: in many Scheme implementations, the `(world)` part of both lists is actually shared. This sharing would be impossible for arrays.

---

Addendum: To answer compman's point that recursion is somehow "non-production-grade", in Scheme, all standard looping/iteration is done using tail recursion. Here's a tail-recursive version of `map1`, for example:

```
(define (map1 f l)
  (let loop ((r '())
             (l (reverse l)))
    (if (null? l) r
        (loop (cons (f (car l)) r) (cdr l)))))
```

or, even more simply using `left-fold1`:

```
(define (map1 f l)
  (left-fold1 (lambda (e r) (cons (f e) r))
              '() (reverse l)))
```

`reverse` is a Scheme built-in, but its implementation is equally trivial (and also uses iteration only):

```
(define (reverse l)
  (left-fold1 cons '() l))
```

Comment: It's more than that: lists are defined recursively, which is why they're easy to deal with recursively.  In other words, it's a structure that is sliced in a natural way.  Compare that to arrays: there, you don't deal directly with the structure -- instead, you deal with an index.  It's an important difference.  (And BTW, [HtDP](http://htdp.org/) uses lists and structs extensively for this reason.)

Comment: @Eli: +1 for putting a finger on what I was trying to allude to with the whole "cdring down a list" thing.

Comment: A library, production-grade version of <code>map</code> could use iteration.

Comment: @compman: It could, and it's trivial to write (just pair left-fold with reverse), but it detracts from the point of my post, which is that these sorts of things can't quite as easily be done with arrays. (Just for the record: in Scheme, iteration is done using tail recursion; Scheme has no `goto` primitive, other than continuations, and nobody does simple looping using continuations. So a "production-grade" `map` still won't be using indices.)

Comment: compman: Um, yeah, you're right -- and given that Chris's code is in Scheme, it *does* use iteration (via tail-calls).  Good scheme compilers (and a few CL compilers too) will actually compile such code to an iteration.

Comment: Actually all these examples would work with an array as the basic element. You don't need an index along with anything in arrays. If you can think of the array as a pointer (like in C), then `(car a)` is obtained by dereferencing a pointer, and `(cdr a)` is incremeting a pointer. The biggest problem with arrays is that you cannot store anything in `(cdr a)`, so you cannot build tree structures.

Comment: Now that I thought a little bit more, the biggest problem is pointer invalidation through array re-allocations when adding elements to the beginning of an array. You need double indirection, and a whole lot of work to handle that.

Comment: @Dysaster: Let's keep it functional and assume that all arrays are immutable (just like Racket has immutable dotted pairs by default). Then you don't have to worry about array reallocations. However, building arrays piecemeal is then impractical.

Comment: Dysaster: obviously, you can make it work with arrays like that, since you just need to implement the minimal list "api".  But doing that removes the reason people use arrays in the first place -- and *that* means an index, and no structural induction.

Comment: I wish we could mark favorite answers.

Comment: But wouldn't sharing storage introduce ownership hell? It feels like it really complicates memory management to the point where GC is a necessity.

Answer (score 2):

Insertion itself is O(1) at the beginning of the list.

```
(cons x '(world))
```

Inserts "x" at the beginning of the list containing world. If you have an array and you want to insert an element at the beginning, you have to shift everything over by one. Not so with lists!

Comment: You'd have to create a new array and copy all the elements anyway, if you want to stay faithful to side-effect-free programming, because arrays cannot share structure. So "shifting everything over by one" is a bit of a red herring. :-)

Comment: I'm also going to unofficially "accept" this answer as well.

Answer (score 1):

Some lisps used to use a technique known as [CDR coding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CDR_coding) fro list representation. This, essentially, replaces the CDR-half of the cell with the contents of the pointed-to cell, allowing you to represent a list with what's effectively an array of CAR pointers, while preserving list semantics (you can have part of a list CDR coded, share CDR-coded tails and other things that normal lists can handle)

However, efficient implementation of CDR coding requires hardware support, so it (as far as I understand) pretty much went out with dedicated Lisp machines.

As far as lisp-the-language-family is concerned, no, I don't think macros would be easier to write. At best, I think it would be no harder to write macros.